# Program terminates before to start the second input stream

Tags: c++, vector, reference

After inserting names, and then terminating the input stream pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Unix) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (Win), the program would to prompt another time, to insert ages, but it isn't so. Please, can you tell me why? Thanks.

here, I use the reference for a printing function not present in this code.

compile online https://onlinegdb.com/BkFNcWSgv - there is the same code below: ↓

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

const vector<string>& read_names(vector<string> &n) {
   for(string temp; cin >> temp;)
      n.push_back(temp);
   return n;
};

const vector<double>& read_ages(vector<double> &a) {
   for(double temp; cin >> temp;)
      a.push_back(temp);
   return a;
};

int main()
{
   vector<string> name;
   vector<string>& nn = name;

   vector<double> age;
   vector<double>& aa = age;


   nn = read_names(name);
   aa = read_ages(age);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, because you are terminating the program. You'll need to find some other way to figure out when to start inputting ages instead of names. Also, why are you both passing in the vector by reference, and returning it? You only need to do one or the other.

Comment: @cigien _"Yes, because you are terminating the program."_ How is the program terminated? In Linux Ctrl+D sends EOF to stdin. The program continues but `cin` doesn't block anymore.

Comment: The behavior of Ctrl+D depends on your terminal. I tried it in VSCode and there it seems to close the input stream. In my Linux terminal Ctrl-D sends EOF. After `std::cin.clear()` I can read user input. It behaves different in VSCode and Tilix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of Ctrl+D depends on your terminal. I tried it in VSCode and there it seems to close the input stream. I wasn't able to reopen it.

In my Linux terminal (Tilix) Ctrl-D sends EOF. After `std::cin.clear()` the `goodbit` is set and I can read user input again. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate

It behaves different in VSCode and Tilix.

The following code works for me. I don't know the behavior in Windows, Mac or other OS.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

const std::vector<std::string>& read_names(std::vector<std::string>& n) {
  for (std::string temp; std::cin >> temp;) n.push_back(temp);
  return n;
}

const std::vector<double>& read_ages(std::vector<double>& a) {
  for (double temp; std::cin >> temp;) a.push_back(temp);
  return a;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> name;
  std::vector<std::string>& nn = name;

  std::vector<double> age;
  std::vector<double>& aa = age;

  //std::cout << std::cin.rdstate() << '\n';
  nn = read_names(name);
  //std::cout << std::cin.rdstate() << '\n';
  std::cin.clear();
  //std::cout << std::cin.rdstate() << '\n';
  aa = read_ages(age);

  std::cout << nn.size() << '\n';
  std::cout << aa.size() << '\n';
  //std::cout << std::cin.rdstate() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```